# What's the point of setting query param values in Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a query param in Azure APIM called `sort` that has `Ascending` and `Descending` as the "values".

What does this actually do?

I'm still able to call this endpoint and pass in values other than `Ascending` and `Descending`, and the value gets forwarded to the backend service without any issues.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a documentation/guidance and predefined values for your web Apis so the developers who use the developer portal know what the right and accepted values to be supplied there. You as an Api author has the decision of how to deal with the non-complaint values which you can enforce through the APIM policies and policy expression.

Comment: This can also be useful when testing via the test tab in APIM. Stored values can easily be selected instead of typing manually.